# Copying dealer attributes from one row into rows for other branches

Tags: performance, sql, sql-server

I am writing an update statement where I need to have multiple rows of data duplicate an existing line with everything but the principal and branch id.

I am fully aware that this code is not the best way of doing things, but today has been one of those days where I would have put my left shoe on my right hand and my right glove on my ear.

Looking at the execution plan, for what little data I am copying I am using 11% cost for each data item.

```
UPDATE CEQBA SET 
    CURR_SYMB           = (select CURR_SYMB         FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch)
   ,VAT_TEXT            = (select VAT_TEXT          FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch)
   ,DAYS_VALID_NR       = (select DAYS_VALID_NR     FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch)
   ,DAYS_FOLLOW_UP_NR   = (select DAYS_FOLLOW_UP_NR FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch)
   ,SUNDRY_CHRG         = (select SUNDRY_CHRG       FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch)
   ,INCL_TAX_FG         = (select INCL_TAX_FG       FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch)
   ,PARTS_TAX_RATE      = (select PARTS_TAX_RATE    FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch)
   ,LABR_TAX_RATE       = (select LABR_TAX_RATE     FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch)
   ,WARR_TAX_RATE       = (select WARR_TAX_RATE     FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch)
   ,DOC_LANG_CD         = (select DOC_LANG_CD       FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch)
   ,ESCALATOR_FACTOR    = (select ESCALATOR_FACTOR  FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch)
   ,ESCALATOR_FG        = (select ESCALATOR_FG      FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch)
   ,DISP_PART_NR_FG     = (select DISP_PART_NR_FG   FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch)
   ,VIEW_PRFTB_FG       = (select VIEW_PRFTB_FG     FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch)
   ,PL_UPD_REMIND_PD    = (select PL_UPD_REMIND_PD  FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch)
   ,WEAR_PART_FG        = (select WEAR_PART_FG      FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch)
   ,AREA_TYPE_CD        = (select AREA_TYPE_CD      FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch)
   ,OIL_SAMP_INCL_FG    = (select OIL_SAMP_INCL_FG  FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch)
   ,WARR_EMAIL_ADDR     = (select WARR_EMAIL_ADDR   FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch) 
WHERE 
    PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode
AND     BRANCH_ACC_CD IN (select * from dbo.fn_SplitString(@ToBranch,','))
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CEQBA](
[PRNCPL_ACC_CD] [char](10) NOT NULL,
[BRANCH_ACC_CD] [char](10) NOT NULL,
[CURR_SYMB] [char](3) NULL,
[VAT_TEXT] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[DAYS_VALID_NR] [smallint] NULL,
[DAYS_FOLLOW_UP_NR] [smallint] NULL,
[SUNDRY_CHRG] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
[INCL_TAX_FG] [char](1) NULL,
[PARTS_TAX_RATE] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
[LABR_TAX_RATE] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
[WARR_TAX_RATE] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
[DOC_LANG_CD] [char](2) NOT NULL,
[ESCALATOR_FACTOR] [decimal](5, 2) NOT NULL,
[ESCALATOR_FG] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[DISP_PART_NR_FG] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[VIEW_PRFTB_FG] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[PL_UPD_REMIND_PD] [int] NULL,
[WEAR_PART_FG] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[AREA_TYPE_CD] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[OIL_SAMP_INCL_FG] [char](1) NOT NULL,
[WARR_EMAIL_ADDR] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[DFLT_ALLOW_CHG_FG] [char](1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.CEQBA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[PRNCPL_ACC_CD] ASC,
[BRANCH_ACC_CD] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: That must be awful slow with all those inline subqueries. Is this part of a stored procedure or an ad hoc script? If a proc, could you include the header showing the arguments?

Comment: @Phrancis its not slow but its not as quick as I would like it either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after walking away and then evaluating the solution again this morning, I am using a CTE to get my data and then updating this way

```
------Dealer Settings Start--------
    WITH DEALER_SETTINGS AS 
    (select      CURR_SYMB          AS NEW_CURR_SYMB 
                ,VAT_TEXT           AS NEW_VAT_TEXT         
                ,DAYS_VALID_NR      AS NEW_DAYS_VALID_NR        
                ,DAYS_FOLLOW_UP_NR  AS NEW_DAYS_FOLLOW_UP_NR    
                ,SUNDRY_CHRG        AS NEW_SUNDRY_CHRG      
                ,INCL_TAX_FG        AS NEW_INCL_TAX_FG      
                ,PARTS_TAX_RATE     AS NEW_PARTS_TAX_RATE   
                ,LABR_TAX_RATE      AS NEW_LABR_TAX_RATE        
                ,WARR_TAX_RATE      AS NEW_WARR_TAX_RATE        
                ,DOC_LANG_CD        AS NEW_DOC_LANG_CD      
                ,ESCALATOR_FACTOR   AS NEW_ESCALATOR_FACTOR 
                ,ESCALATOR_FG       AS NEW_ESCALATOR_FG     
                ,DISP_PART_NR_FG    AS NEW_DISP_PART_NR_FG  
                ,VIEW_PRFTB_FG      AS NEW_VIEW_PRFTB_FG        
                ,PL_UPD_REMIND_PD   AS NEW_PL_UPD_REMIND_PD 
                ,WEAR_PART_FG       AS NEW_WEAR_PART_FG     
                ,AREA_TYPE_CD       AS NEW_AREA_TYPE_CD     
                ,OIL_SAMP_INCL_FG   AS NEW_OIL_SAMP_INCL_FG 
                ,WARR_EMAIL_ADDR    AS NEW_WARR_EMAIL_ADDR

    FROM CEQBA WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch)
    UPDATE CEQBA SET 
                 CURR_SYMB          = NEW_CURR_SYMB         
                ,VAT_TEXT           = NEW_VAT_TEXT          
                ,DAYS_VALID_NR      = NEW_DAYS_VALID_NR     
                ,DAYS_FOLLOW_UP_NR  = NEW_DAYS_FOLLOW_UP_NR 
                ,SUNDRY_CHRG        = NEW_SUNDRY_CHRG       
                ,INCL_TAX_FG        = NEW_INCL_TAX_FG       
                ,PARTS_TAX_RATE     = NEW_PARTS_TAX_RATE    
                ,LABR_TAX_RATE      = NEW_LABR_TAX_RATE     
                ,WARR_TAX_RATE      = NEW_WARR_TAX_RATE     
                ,DOC_LANG_CD        = NEW_DOC_LANG_CD       
                ,ESCALATOR_FACTOR   = NEW_ESCALATOR_FACTOR  
                ,ESCALATOR_FG       = NEW_ESCALATOR_FG      
                ,DISP_PART_NR_FG    = NEW_DISP_PART_NR_FG   
                ,VIEW_PRFTB_FG      = NEW_VIEW_PRFTB_FG     
                ,PL_UPD_REMIND_PD   = NEW_PL_UPD_REMIND_PD  
                ,WEAR_PART_FG       = NEW_WEAR_PART_FG      
                ,AREA_TYPE_CD       = NEW_AREA_TYPE_CD      
                ,OIL_SAMP_INCL_FG   = NEW_OIL_SAMP_INCL_FG  
                ,WARR_EMAIL_ADDR    = NEW_WARR_EMAIL_ADDR
    FROM DEALER_SETTINGS                
    WHERE 
            PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode AND BRANCH_ACC_CD IN (select * from dbo.fn_SplitString(@ToBranch,','));
```

Comment: That looks **way better**!

Comment: @Phrancis yea the execution plan is a lot better too.  The main reason for doing what I am doing is to reduct a potential 2000 ( yes, two thousand) calls to the database doing one row and one column from a .Net Data Table from an application and reduce it down to one call to the database and let SQL Server do the 'heavy' work.  Current process is having issues, new process although in development and using a smaller subset of data is reliable and pretty damn quick  given how much data access is needed across 11 tables

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to implement some thing as below pseudocode.

```
select column1, column2, column3 into variable1, variable2, variable3
from CEQBA 
WHERE PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode and BRANCH_ACC_CD = @FromBranch

update 
CEQBA 
set column1 = variable1,
column2 = variable2
where PRNCPL_ACC_CD = @DealerCode
AND BRANCH_ACC_CD IN (select * from dbo.fn_SplitString(@ToBranch,','))
```